# how to add Delivery estimate below product title in woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

i want to show Estimated delivery days below the product title to let my customers know when they will receive their order like in page below.

I want it to show different days based on shipping class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this below free plugin. It's match your current scenario.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-estimated-shipping-date/